Компонент не обновляется в React v6 textarea при изминении величины в меньшую сторону
При изменении высоты в блоке <textarea> изменяется только в большую сторону
export const Chat = ()=>{
   const [inputHeight, setInputHeight] = useState(null);
   const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

   useEffect(()=>{
       setValue(inputHeight);
   },[inputHeight])
   


   const onChangeInputHeight = (e)=>{
       setInputHeight(e.target.scrollHeight)
   }


   return (
       <div className={style.wrap}>
           <div className={style.heder}>
               <h2>Chat</h2>
               <p>0 users in the room</p>
               <button>Left the room</button>
           </div>
           <div className={style.message}>

           </div>
           <div className={style.message_btn} >
               <textarea  
               type="text" 
               placeholder="Your message" 
               className={style.input}
               onChange={onChangeInputHeight}
               style={{height:value}}
               
               />
               <button className={style.btn}>Send</button>
           </div>
       </div>

   )
}` 

